# Clean URLs enabled but main-menu keeps replacing clean URL with ugly node/ URL

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have enabled clean URL's on my website and had a menu item in my main-menu that pointed to a View that had a URL alias set up for /ebook-register. I just removed that alias and assigned the same alias up to a page (content item). However now the menu item keeps getting set to node/2 instead of ebook-register. How can I get the menu to stop changing my clean URL into ugliness? If I manually navigate to localhost/ebook-register I get to the right page, and under URL aliases in the admin I can see the alias and confirmed it's pointing to the correct page, and the menu doesn't throw an error when I set ebook-register to the path so it's finding the alias.

It does give me the following message:

> The menu system stores system paths only, but will use the URL alias for display. ebook-register has been stored as node/2.

However, despite saying it will display the clean URL, clicking the link sends you to the ugly node/2 URL.

I am using Drupal 7 and have tried clearing the cache already.

Comment: If you hover on menu item, what it will shows?

Comment: localhost/node/2

Comment: Re-reading my answer, I think I must have misunderstood part of your question (sorry!) I would check two further things: 1) that you get the same result from the node form and from the `admin/structure/menu`, and 2) that you get the same result if you create a new node and try to add a menu item (I have once or twice had nodes in Drupal that seemed to 'go bad' where nothing I could do would fix them, but copying and pasting the content to another node actually worked...)

Answer (score 0):

You need to also install the [Global Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module to handle redirection to aliases.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.drupal.org/project/pathologic will convert node id link to your pathauto pretty links. This will fix it in your menu.  Additionally, You can configure it to work with your CKEditor too.